# Can I return to Tap & Go when the step has previously been bypassed?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, motorola

I have a new moto maxx 2, and when I first started it, one of the setup prompts was to use Tap & Go. That was successfully initiated, but did not complete because the old phone turned off. I want to go back and complete the process, but can't find any way to go back to that screen. It's not even in the setup wizard. Thoughts?